# Jquery autocomplete not showing result, looks like results is hidden somehow

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Can you please help me to figure out where is the problem is? In a search box, autocomplete jquery function (response, request) not giving me the results, Looks like it grabbing the expected data from the database but result is hidden instead showing the list of line. here is the image how the list line looks like.

[image: [enter image description here]

[image]

```
             <div> <form class="navbar-seach pull-center">
                    <div><input type="text" placeholder="Search Product" style="width:550px; height:40px;padding-left: 10px;margin-top: 20px;" id="searchBox" onkeyup="if (event.keyCode === 13) {searchResults(this.value); this.value = '';}"></div>
                </form>
```

Comment: Wow. I advise you to read [tour] and [mcve]

Comment: I could be lame, but have you ever heard of screenshot (`prnt scrn` key)? And please, post your code.

Comment: Edit your post to insert html and js

Comment: <form class="navbar-seach pull-center" autocomplete="off">
                        <div><input type="text" placeholder="Search Product" style="width:550px; height:40px;padding-left: 10px;margin-top: 20px;" id="searchBox" onkeyup="if (event.keyCode === 13) {searchResults(this.value); this.value = '';}"></div>
                    </form> --------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: just remove `autocomplete="off"`

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion. I tried  but it does not work.